# ActiveRecord query Model by Association attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my code, a Room has_many :users, and Users have a :name attribute

Let's also say I have NameArr, an array of names.

What's the best way to get all Rooms that have all the users in Arr?

(e.g. if Arr = ["John", "Mark", "Matt"] then I want all Rooms having a User with name "John" AND a User with name "Mark" AND a User with name "Matt")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
Room.joins(:users).where("users.name in (?)", nameArr).group("rooms.id").having("count(distinct users.name)=?", nameArr.count)
```

Comment: I believe this solves the question if I'm looking for Rooms having a User with name "John" OR a User with name "Mark"... but I'm looking for Rooms having a User with name "John" AND a User with name "Mark"

Thanks!

Comment: As per your new requirement, you want the behavior Like **IN** query with **AND** the except **OR**. There is no default clause in mysql for this, so we need to create the custom query for that purpose. I build a query for you please try this
`Room.joins(:users).where("users.name in (?)", nameArr).group("rooms.id").having("count(distinct users.name)=?", nameArr.count)`

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully that will work, please give a try. 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome :) . Please don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `INNER JOIN` to meet the need.

```
Room.joins(:users).
    where(users: { name:  ["John", "Mark", "Matt"] } )
```

Comment: I think `joins(:user).where(user: { name: [] })` needs to be `joins(:users).where(users: { name: [] } )` ... I believe the join and where clause have to use the table name (plural) ... but let me know if not :)! Might've misread something!

Comment: @craig.kaminsky You are right.. I had deadly typo.. Untried code.. wrote from concept, so it is buggy..:)

Comment: LOL! I do that all the time :). Have a great weekend!

Comment: I believe this gets Rooms having a user with name "John" OR a user with name "Mark" OR a user with name "Matt", correct?

I was hoping instead to get Rooms having a user with name "John" AND a user with name "Mark" AND a user with name "Matt". 

Could this answer be modified to work for that? Thanks!